# Poly-fill for bind without call or apply

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write poly-fill function for the bind function without call or apply method. Below is the code, my doubt is what will happen if the "ctx" object has "fnToCall" methods already in it. Doing the below will override the function, so what is the correct/better way to write poly fill without call or apply

```
Function.prototype.newBindWithoutApply = function (ctx, ...args) {
 
 ctx.fnToCall = this;
 // returning the new method with context
 return function (...args1) {
  allArguments = [...allArguments, ...args1]
  return ctx.fnToCall(...args)
 }
}
```

Comment: Use a [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) if you're afraid of name clashes.

Comment: can you give an example @kikon

Comment: Here's an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jq7wok5/). Of course, if name clashes is the only problem you're facing, you can devise a simple way to generate strings in a loop until you find one that is not a key of the object you want to bind the function to, like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9g1p3dzL/)

Comment: Since there's an error in the fiddles, and I see there's no other answer, I'll add post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a small correction to your code and to my previous fiddles in messages, a solution based on `Symbol` can be:

```js
Function.prototype.newBindWithoutApply = function (ctx, ...args) {
  const fnToCall = Symbol();
  ctx[fnToCall] = this;
  return function (...args1) {
    return ctx[fnToCall](...[...args, ...args1])
  }
}

const o = {fnToCall: 1, fnToCall0: 2};
const f =  function(x, y, z){
    console.log({"this":this, x, y, z});
}
const fBound = f.newBindWithoutApply(o, 11, 22);
fBound(33)
fBound(44)

const o2 = {fnToCall: 'a', fnToCall0: 'b'};

// binding an already bound function doesn't 
//change "this", but may bind unbound arguments
const fBound2 = fBound.newBindWithoutApply(o2, 99);
fBound2();
```

If `Symbol` is also not available, name clashes could be avoided by changing the name of the function in a loop until you find one that isn't a key of the object you bind the function to:

```js
Function.prototype.newBindWithoutApply = function (ctx, ...args) {
    let fnToCall = "fnToCall";
  let i = 0;
  while(fnToCall in ctx){
    fnToCall = "fnToCall"+i;
    i++;
  }
  // "hide" the entry - enumerable is false by default
  Object.defineProperty(ctx, fnToCall, {value: this});
  return function (...args1) {
    return ctx[fnToCall](...[...args, ...args1])
  }
}

const o = {fnToCall: 1, fnToCall0: 2};
const f =  function(x, y, z){
    console.log({"this":this, x, y, z});
}
const fBound = f.newBindWithoutApply(o, 11, 22);
fBound(33);
fBound(44);

const o2 = {fnToCall: 'a', fnToCall0: 'b'};

// binding an already bound function doesn't 
//change "this", but may bind unbound arguments
const fBound2 = fBound.newBindWithoutApply(o2, 99);
fBound2();
```